# Show DetailView within tabbarcontroller/navigation hierarchy from remote notification

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, push-notification, uitabbarcontroller

i scoured countless posts over a few days and never found any one exactly correct answer to my seemingly straight-forward task:

My app has a main tabbarcontroller (tbc) with the first tab having a simple view controller, and the rest having a navigationcontroller-oriented hierarchy.

The task is simple: accept an inbound remote notification, and fire up a detail form (dv) that is one level deeper than the root view of the 4th tab’s navigation controller (tagged here with id=3).

The tbc is the app’s rootviewVC. The motif’s are working fine. The analysis of the motif all works. Not matter what i tried, it would seem that i could only get the main tbc to show (to tab3) OR the dv to show with correct details but NO tbc in sight.

I eventually got it to work by essentially manually resetting the tbc as per line AAA shown below, but it makes little sense to me that i had to essentially recreate all the tabs in tbc in order to make this work. The answer is likely easy enough, if you know where to look:

SO.. the question: is there a better way to fire up a detail view inside a navigation-oriented hierarchy that lives within a tab within a tabbarcontroller which is an app’s rootview?

Working code example:

```
UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *tbc = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AppTabBarController"];

//setup tabs
//TODO: we should not have to create these here as the storyboard already has them...
UINavigationController *mainViewController = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tab0NavController"];
UINavigationController *Tab1NavController = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tab1NavController"];
UINavigationController *Tab2NavController = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tab2NavController"];
UINavigationController *Tab3NavController = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tab3NavController"];

[self.window setRootViewController:tbc];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//setup the destination detail view to show & set its' property we must manage (temp only, real code uses payload
QTManageContactVC *vc3 = [Tab3NavController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“Tab3VC"];
PFObject *newWidget = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@“Widget"];
{set details code}
vc2.widget = newConnection;

//AAA 
[tbc setViewControllers:@[mainViewController, Tab1NavController, Tab2NavController, Tab3NavController]];
[tbc setSelectedIndex:3];
[Tab3NavController pushViewController:vc3 animated:NO];

completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
return;
```

Comment: perhaps this was too detailed, or not isolated enough to answer.. All i know is that i must be missing something basic when tabs show views that all have differing navcontrollers. I am having an odd time trying to get simple pushviewcontroller calls to actually show the view i want.. The above does work, but seems like too much.

My thoughts are simply to grab the navcontroller of the tab i need, via storyboard id, set the tabbarcontroller's navcontroller to that, then push the views onto that navcontroller to enter into the detail view i need. 

Seems simple, but without the above.. no go.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with the arrangement, here it is:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];                        
[(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController setSelectedIndex:YourIndexValue];

UINavigationController *nav = [[(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:YourIndexValue];
YourViewController *targetVC = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ManageContactVC"];                        

[nav pushViewController:targetVC animated:NO];
```